# Initializing a Char*[]

Tags: c++, arrays, cstring

Question is in the title, how do I initialize a char*[] and give values to it in C++, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the stl ? as in std::vector<std::string> ?

Comment: ` ... = { "hello", "world" }` didn't work?

Comment: because a std::vector<std::string> is a waste where  char*[] will do?

Comment: @Chris: You are totally underestimating the compiler. Modern C++ compilers have very aggressive optimizers.

Comment: @Chris: Waste of _what_?

Comment: @sbi: maybe a waste of simplicity ? ;-)

Comment: @kriss: Well, `char*[]` doesn't really seem to be all that easy.

Comment: Waste of robustness, perhaps.  Or a waste of a lack of memory leaks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Though you're probably aware, char*[] is an array of pointers to characters, and I would guess you want to store a number of strings. Initializing an array of such pointers is as simple as:

```
char ** array = new char *[SIZE];
```

...or if you're allocating memory on the stack:

```
char * array[SIZE];
```

You would then probably want to fill the array with a loop such as:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    // str is likely to be an array of characters
    array[i] = str;
}
```

As noted in the comments for this answer, if you're allocating the array with new (dynamic allocation) remember to delete your array with:

```
delete[] array;
```

Comment: `char ** array = new char[SIZE];` should be `char ** array = new char *[SIZE];`

Comment: You may also remind that if array is allocated dynamically it should be deleted using `delete [] array` (using `delete array` is a current newbie mistake).

Answer (score 13):

Depending on what you want to initialize to you could do any of:

```
char mystr[] = {'h','i',0};
char * myotherstring = "my other string";
char * mythirdstring = "goodbye";

char * myarr[] = {0};
char * myarr[] = {&mystr, myotherstring};
char * myarr[10];
char * myarr[10] = {0};
char * myarr[10] = {&mystr, myotherstring, mythirdstring, 0};
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Wouldn't `&mystr` and `&myotherstring` resolve to a type of `char[]*`, which isn't the array initializer's expected `char*`?

Comment: I edited my answer slightly, and as it is now it should work.

Comment: There is also the issue of the difference between a char * and a const char * My compiler use to raise a warning whenever I try to assign a const char * (constant strings) to a char *.

Comment: ya... this was really intended to demonstrate initialization rather than compiler satisfaction :)

Comment: To fix g++ errors: `char mystr[] = {'h','i',0};
const char * myotherstring = "my other string";
const char * mythirdstring = "goodbye";

char * myarr[] = {0};
const char * myarr1[] = {(char *)&mystr, myotherstring};
char * myarr2[10];
char * myarr3[10] = {0};
const char * myarr4[10] = {(char *)&mystr, myotherstring, mythirdstring, 0};`

Answer (score 11):

One thing I have noticed that you must be careful of... C and C++ have diverged a bit in initialization syntax.  As Mark B. points out above, you can initialize an array of char pointers thusly:

```
const char* messages[] =
{
    "Beginning",
    "Working",
    "Finishing",
    "Done"
};
```

But in C++. as kriss points out, this nets you a warning about a deprecated conversion from string to char*.  That's because C++ assumes you'll want to use strings for strings ;-}.

That's not always true.  So when you really do want to initialize an array of char*, I have found that I have to do it like so:

```
const char* messages[] =
{
    (char*)("Beginning"),
    (char*)("Working"),
    (char*)("Finishing"),
    (char*)("Done")
};
```

The compiler is now happy...

Comment: std::string gets a bit heavy when working in C++ for embedded devices.  Resources are rather limited and std::string adds quite a bit of overhead that serves no purpose for simple string contants.

I certainly appreciate this advice, as tedious as it can be for large arrays of string contants.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
char* my_c_string;
char* x[] = { "hello", "world", 0, my_c_string };
```

Comment: This is very good example. 0 would help in terminating the loop as well if any function just takes argument as 
void foo( char * x[] )
you don't need to have another variable to find the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Like that:

```
char p1 = 'A';
char p2 = 'B';
char * t[] = {&p1, &p2};

std::cout << "p1=" << *t[0] << ", p2=" << *t[1] << std::endl;
```

But somehow I believe that's not the answer to the real question...

I you want an array of C strings defined at compile time you should use an array of const char * instead:

```
const char * t2[] = {"string1", "string2"};

std::cout << "p1=" << t2[0] << ", p2=" << t2[1] << std::endl;
```

Without the const my compiler would say :
    warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want a C-style array of constant strings (for example indexed messages):

```
const char* messages[] =
{
    "Beginning",
    "Working",
    "Finishing",
    "Done"
};
```

If however you're trying to maintain a container of runtime variable strings, using the C++ facility `std::vector<std::string>` will make keeping track of all the memory operations much easier.

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::string my_string("Hello, world.")
strings.push_back("String1");
strings.push_back(my_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other array:

```
char *a, *b, *c;
char* cs[] = {a, b, c}; // initialized
cs[0] = b; // assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **strings = new char *[2]; // create an array of two character pointers
    strings[0] = "hello"; // set the first pointer in the array to "hello"
    strings[1] = "world"; // set the second pointer in the array to "world"

    // loop through the array and print whatever it points to out with a space
    // after it
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << strings[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```